# RHEL Permission Denied whilst trying to Run Robot Framework

Tags: python, linux, robotframework, rhel8

I am setting up Robot Framework on RHEL 8.4. I have python 3.6 installed on my machine. However, when I try to run robot from within python virtual environment it throws

-ksh: robot: cannot execute [Permission Denied]

I also ran whereis robot and gave all permissions to the robot file.

The error happens when I am trying to run robot as a user other than root from within the virtual environment however, it works fine when run within virtual environment as root.

However, I am not keen to continue normal development as root and would like this to work via my normal user.

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve], i.e. a list of exact steps that reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds quite strange but upgrading PIP resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a new project. Select the parent directory to the folder where the RobotFramework file is stored. It will solve the problem.

`C:\Robot Framework`

[image]